# How can I avoid seeing "sum()" at the top of a query where I've summed two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

In the same row as this formula, I see `sum()` with the accurate results below.  How can I remove this text from the results?

```excel
=QUERY(projectTasksAdj!A3:R51,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G+H",0)
```

[image: shee]

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=244517454&range=A2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the clause "label"
Try this:

```
=QUERY(projectTasksAdj!A3:T51,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G+H where I is not NULL label G+H ''",0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Makes perfect sense after seeing your formula.  It was just labeling it to tell me where it came from.  Such a simple fix!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

also a possible solution (especially very handy when lots of labels needs to be defined/removed):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(projectTasksAdj!A3:T51, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G+H 
  where I is not null", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```